# Trying to put a divider between each menu item on WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu

I am trying to put a "//" between every menu item on my WordPress menu. The only place I don't want one is obviously on the last one.

Example:

Our Story // Our Products // Meet The Team // Contact Us

I have tried some css, but couldn't get it to work.

my header.php file is showing:

```
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">                    
                    <?php 
                            $walker = new rc_scm_walker;
                            wp_nav_menu(array(
                            'theme_location'  => 'main-navigation',
                            'fallback_cb'     => false,
                            'container'       => false,
                            'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s">%3$s</ul>',
                            'walker'          => $walker
                        ));
                    ?>           
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

My navigations id is "site-navigation" and the class is "main-navigation".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all your selectors, you could use pseudo elements to do something like this:

```
.main-navigation li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.main-navigation li:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '//';
}

.main-navigation li:last-child:after {
  content: '';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8eghhh2v/

Comment: Thanks! I think this is going to work perfectly. Thanks again!